# Clear cell contents when another cell is changed

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

In Excel i have two dependent drop down lists that use an if statement to determine what is in the lists depending on what is in cell B8.

I would like to add in the VBA code if B8 is changed then clear any selected items in Cells B14 & B15

I have tried the following

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = Range("B8").Address Then
Range("B14:B15").Value = ""
End If
End Sub
```

But i get the error `Ambiguous name detected:Worksheet_Change`

Comment: And what have you tried to achieve your goal? Start by looking up and getting familiar with `Worksheet_Change` and `Worksheet_SelectionChange` events

Comment: Updated Question with code i have currently

Comment: Ok. `Ambiguous name` means that you probably have two `Worksheet_Change` subs within the same module. Is that true?

Comment: Yeh, can i just embed this one into the other worksheet_change?

Comment: There must be duplicate worksheet_change event.

Comment: @Matt you should be able to just add the body of this `Worksheet_change` event to the other one but I can't see the full code so I am just guessing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed it to a `SelectionChange` and it worked.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = Range("B8").Address Then
Range("B14:B15").Value = ""
End If
End Sub
```